# I want merge two maps in one combined map

Tags: groovy

I have the following maps defined

```
def Map1 = [
             Rate: 0,
             Exceptions: [ Exceptions: [ [:] ]
           ]
def Map2 = [
            Exceptions: [Exceptions: [ [:] ] ]
           ]
```

Map1 already has data

```
Map1 = [
         Rate: 0, 
         Exceptions: [
                      Exception: [
                                   [Code: 5, Message: "Error"],
                                   [Code: 65, Message: "Error"],
                                   [Code: 35, Message: "Error"]
                      ]
         ]
       ]
```

and I want to add Map2 to Map1

```
Map2 = [
          Exceptions: [
                        Exception: [
                                     [Code: 6, Message: "Error"],
                                     [Code: 25, Message: "Error"],
                                     [Code: 15, Message: "Error"]
                        ]
             ]
           ]
```

I know I could a

```
Map2.Exceptions.Exception.each{ Exception ->
  Map1.Exceptions.Exception.add(Exception)
}
```

but is there way to have Groovy do it? i.e. `Map1.merge(Map2)`

Edit: I ended up creating a meta class method to handle the merger. It's recursive and doesn't handle any non Map/List variables that already exists but it does what I need it to do.

```
Map.metaClass.Merge = { Map Source ->
        Map Destination = delegate
        Source.keySet().each{ key ->
            if(Destination.keySet().contains(key)){
                if(!(Source[key] instanceof Map)){
                    if(Source[key] instanceof List){
                        Source[key].each{ Value ->
                            Destination[key].add(Value)
                        }//Source[Key].each
                    }//if(Source[key] instanceof List)
                }//if(!(Source[key] instanceof Map))
                else{
                    Destination[key].Merge(Source[key])
                }//else(!(Source[key] instanceof Map))
            }//if(Destination.keySet().contains(key))
            else{
                Destination[key] = Source[key]
            }//else(Destination.keySet().contains(key))
        }//Source.keySet().each
    }//Map.metaclass.Merge(Map Source)
```

Comment: Not that I know of as it is very dependant on the structure of your maps and the functionality you want.  THe closest you can get is `(map1 as ConfigObject).merge( map2 as ConfigObject )`, but that isn't the functionality you require as your map2 `Exception` value needs to be added to the map1 Exception list rather than overwriting it as is the default

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```
Map1.Exceptions.Exception += Map2.Exceptions.Exception
print Map1
```

Output:

```
[Rate:0, Exceptions:[Exception:[[Code:5, Message:Error], [Code:65, Message:Error], [Code:35, Message:Error], [Code:6, Message:Error], [Code:25, Message:Error], [Code:15, Message:Error]]]]
```

Comment: Wish I saw your response before I started working on the method to extend the Map class. Oh well. Thanks though.

Comment: Well my response only works in this specific case. For example Map1.Exceptions += Map2.Exceptions wouldn't work, because it would only contain the elements of Map2.Exceptions. If you can guarantee that the structure always looks like in your example my response will work, but so will your .each closure. So maybe you didn't do all the work for nothing :)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken then this will work only on the first level of map structure. In case of nested structures when second map is filled only partially this approach will fail.  [foo: 'aaa', bar: [buzz: 'bbb', qux: 'ccc']] + [bar: [buzz: 'ddd']] == [foo:aaa, bar:[buzz:'ddd']]

Comment: Yes pseudo, you're right